# Yii2 ActiveRecord query caching. How to know?

Tags: caching, activerecord, yii2

I am starting to dip my first fingers in Yii2 framework. When querying for data with ActiveRecord I want to use query caching. I query like this:

```
$BestCustomers = SaleOrder::getDb()->cache(function ($db) {
    return SaleOrder::find()
        ->with(['preOrder', 'invoice', 'articlesOut', 'articlesOut.product'])
        ->limit(8)->all();
});
```

Seems to work, but how to know if its really getting data from cache instead of Database?

From performance side I dont see any major changes, thats why im conserned if it is really working.

Comment: Easiest way is to change something in DB and see if the `$BestCustomers` is the same or not.

Comment: have you properly configured data caching in your config? .. eventually show your app/config/main.php   ..component section please ,..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Knowing when cache is hit

You have several options. The code within your callable is only executed when the data is refetched. Therefore if you write a log-entry or set a breakpoint in there, you will know when data is loaded from your DB.
You can also truncate your cache, reload the page and compare the filesize (FileCache) or the db-entries of your cache-table (DB Cache). This all depends on your cache config.

#### Duration and  dependency

If you want to be more specific about when to load data, how long your cache is valid and what it depends upon, have a look at the params of the cache-function. You find the code with doc [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/db/Connection.php#L428).
 Simply set a [dependency](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/caching/Dependency.php) and you're good.

#### Cache config

Two parts are involved here. First configure your cache component to use one of Yii2s [several options](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-caching-data.html#supported-cache-storage). This is done within the config-file in the `cache`-section. The most common ones are the file- and db-cache.

```
'cache'=>[
    'class'=>'yii\caching\DbCache',
],
```

If you want to use the DB-cache you first have to apply a migration creating your cache-table. You can find the migration in the yii-folder under `vendor\yiisoft\yii2\caching\migrations`. If you use the file cache, this step is not needed.

#### DB-Config for caching

Next you want to make sure your DB-component is configured the right way. There are several properties relevant for caching. The most important ones being `enableSchemaCache` and `enableQueryCache`. Especially the first of the two has a massive impact on performance. It's a good idea to set both of those depending on your debug-status. Here's an example how I tend to configure a db-connection for caching:

```
return [
    'class'=>'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn'=>'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxxxx-local',
    'username'=>'root',
    'password'=>'',
    'charset'=>'utf8',

    'enableSchemaCache'=>!YII_DEBUG,
    'schemaCacheDuration'=>3600,
    'schemaCache'=>'cache',

    'enableQueryCache'=>!YII_DEBUG,
    'queryCacheDuration'=>3600,
];
```

#### Goodie: method to flush cache code-side

This method I use within an action to flush my cache application side. You want to do this after a db-migration to assert the new schema gets recached.

```
protected function flushCache($id='cache')
{
    if (!isset(Yii::$app->{$id}) || !(Yii::$app->{$id} instanceof Cache)) {
        $msg = Yii::t('Invalid cache to flush: {cache}', ['cache'=>$id]);
        throw new InvalidParamException($msg);
    }

    /* @var $cache \yii\caching\Cache */
    $cache = Yii::$app->{$id};
    if ($cache->flush()) {
        $msg = Yii::t('app', 'Successfully flushed cache `{cache}`', ['cache'=>$id]);
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', $msg);
    } else {
        $msg = Yii::t('app', 'Problem while flushing cache `{cache}`', ['cache'=>$id]);
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('danger', $msg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to add the [yii2-debug extension](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-debug) to show the excellent debug toolbar on your site. If you correctly installed and configured the extension, you should see a "toolbar" at the bottom of your Yii2 site. You may need to click it to expand it. Look for the "DB" section to see exactly what queries were run for a given call. If you cache is working correctly, you will only see a given query during the initial page load (before the value has been cached) - subsequent loads should no longer show the query being run.